# Problem with opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) file

Tags: personal-geodatabase

I want to open an Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) file but get the following error code:

> PGeo:qgis is not a valid or recognized data source.

I installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 64 bit and created a new ODBC connection in the SYSTEM-DSN as recommended in other posts. I also tried to add the following two lines:

```
set OGR_SKIP=ODBC
set PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE=DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=%%s
```

in my qgis-grass7.bat file before the last line.

So far I tried every solution I found in the internet.

Does someone have an idea as to what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that personal geodatabases work with a 64 bit driver. Have you also tried the 32 bit version? ArcGIS Pro, which is 64 bit, [doesn't support](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01301-01325-001324.htm) PGDBs either

Comment: That could be the problem. I will try it out. Thanks:)

Comment: Personal geodatabases are definitely 32 bit and you need to using the 32 bit driver for accessing them. That's why Arcpro cannot connect to them natively like ArcMap.